# Extract the first element in the list when second element is minimal

Tags: list-manipulation

There is a list in the form {a,b}, where the list is the numerical solution of some equation; List=Table[z[i]]. I need the "a" when "b" is minimal in the list.

Comment: What do you mean by minimal ? Can you give us a simple example with a list and what you want ?

Comment: `SortBy[list, Last][[1,1]]`

Answer (score 7):

Have you seen [`MinimalBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinimalBy.html)?

```
SeedRandom[2]
v = RandomInteger[99, {7, 2}]

MinimalBy[v, Last]
```

> ```
> {{92, 57}, {22, 84}, {63, 1}, {81, 96}, {19, 38}, {67, 68}, {63, 39}}
>
> {{63, 1}}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

First, I would like to say that `MinimalBy` (in the answers by [@Mr. Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard)/[@UnchartedWorks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/43670/unchartedworks)) is the cleanest way to solve the problem.  It's too bad it's not optimized for arrays.

A small adjustment [@MikeY's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/47314/mikey) use of `Ordering` results in a tremendous performance improvement. I made a reference to it in a comment, but it seems it has not been appreciated in the way I expected.  So I will demonstrate. `Ordering[x, 1]` is a special, optimized case that returns the position of the minimal element in `x`.

```
SeedRandom[2]
v = RandomInteger[10^9, {10^7, 2}];

v[[v[[All, 2]] ~Ordering~ 1]] // AbsoluteTiming
MinimalBy[v, Last] // AbsoluteTiming                    (* Mr. Wizard, UnchartedWorks) 
v[[Ordering[v[[All, 2]]] // First]] // AbsoluteTiming   (* another tweak of MikeY's *)
v[[Ordering[v[[All, 2]]]]] // First // AbsoluteTiming   (* MikeY *)
(*
  {0.188194, {{497087695, 12}}}
  {0.452981, {{497087695, 12}}}
  {2.19028, {497087695, 12}}
  {2.52904, {497087695, 12}}
*)
```

Note: `Ordering[x, -1]` is also a special optimized case that returns the position of the maximal element of `x`.  Other cases of `Ordering` compute the complete ordering, which takes considerably longer.  `Ordering` has been used in these ways in many answers on the site.

```
Ordering[v[[All, 2]], 1] // AbsoluteTiming        (* min position *)
Ordering[v[[All, 2]], -1] // AbsoluteTiming       (* max position *)
Ordering[v[[All, 2]]] // First // AbsoluteTiming  (* min position from complete ordering *)
Ordering[v[[All, 2]], {2}] // AbsoluteTiming      (* 2nd smallest position *)
Ordering[v[[All, 2]], 2] // AbsoluteTiming        (* two smallest positions *)
(*
  {0.188538, {8647676}}
  {0.194112, {323408}}
  {2.15685, 8647676}
  {2.16561, {8296548}}
  {2.16896, {8647676, 8296548}}
*)
```

Answer (score 4):

Made up list

```
 lst = Table[RandomInteger[100, 2], {10}]
```

lst={{24, 100}, {2, 30}, {93, 26}, {37, 86}, {66, 71}, {92, 27}, {94, 
  25}, {16, 39}, {30, 68}, {65, 98}}

Pick off the element you want by ordering the list based on second column

```
lst[[Ordering[lst[[All, 2]]]]] // First
```

{94, 25}

Pick off just element 'a'

```
    lst[[Ordering[lst[[All, 2]]]]] // First// First
```

94

Comment: Have you seen the form `Ordering[lst[[All, 2]], 1]`?

Comment: @Michael E2, definitely more terse

Comment: And faster when put inside `lst[[..]]` -- no reordering of the list.

Answer (score 4):

In:

```
SeedRandom[1];
xss = Table[RandomInteger[100, 2], {10}]
First @@ MinimalBy[xss, Last]
```

Out:

```
{{80, 14}, {0, 67}, {3, 65}, {100, 23}, {97, 68}, {74, 15}, {24, 
  4}, {100, 90}, {83, 70}, {1, 30}}
24
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[2];
v = RandomInteger[99, {7, 2}];

First@SortBy[v, Last]
(* {63, 1} *)
```

also

```
Extract[#, Position[#[[All, 2]], Min[#[[All, 2]]]]] &@v
```